# Date format : Android Contacts Birthday Anniversary

Tags: android, contacts

Working on Contact birthday and Anniversary:

I get details and birthday like this 12.2.2012 or 12/2/2012 or 12-02-2012 or 2/12/12

Question:

1. Is the date Format same across all Samsung Phones. IF yes what is the date format.

   (Guess won't work on all Android phones as birthday dates are stored in many different format)
2. How to identify the date format like if the date  is 12.2.2012 or Feb 12 2012 or any other date string pattern. Is it  of format "yyyy-MM-dd" or "MMM dd, yyyy" or any other?
   ex: if date is "Feb 12 2012" then date format is "MMM dd yyyy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date is stored as "YYYY-MM-DD".

Use the date formater class to convert it into any format you need.

When you want to update put it in the same format as you have read.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it seems different apps/vendors use different formats. My solution for this is to try parsing different formats until i either find the right one or give up.

Here is some sample code:

```
public static final SimpleDateFormat[] birthdayFormats = {
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd"),,
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("yy.MM.dd")
    new SimpleDateFormat("yy/MM/dd"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MMdd"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd"),
    new SimpleDateFormat("MM.dd"),
};
.....
    Date birthday = null;
        for (SimpleDateFormat f : birthdayFormats) {
        try {
                birthday = f.parse(birthdaystr);
                if (birthday!=null) {
                        contact.setBirthday(birthday);
                        break;
                 }
        } catch (Exception e) {
                continue;
        }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateFormat.getDateInstance(int style, Locale locale)` instead of creating your own patterns with SimpleDateFormat.

Another way that u want to get date in String and after pass in below code

```
String dateStr = "04/05/2010"; 

SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr); 
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); 

String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj);
```