# How to change the date format from YYMMDD to YYYY-MM-DD in java?

Tags: java, date-format

I am getting the date format from the machine readable code as YYMMDD, how can i change it into YYYY-MM-DD ?
for example am getting 871223(YYMMDD)
i wand to change it into 1987-12-23(YYYY-MM-DD) 
is it possible ?
can anyone help me with some sample codes?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is you friend, plenty of examples on SO

Comment: [google your question first](https://www.google.com/#q=change+date+format+java)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the question has been answered multiple times before

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert date string to perticular date format "dd-MM-yyyy" in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607201/convert-date-string-to-perticular-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to Date in Different Format in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882420/string-to-date-in-different-format-in-java)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code goes something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat fromUser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

try {

String reformattedStr = myFormat.format(fromUser.parse(inputString));
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: At least link to update docs, Java 7 or 8 would be prefered, as it would highlight any possible changes that have occurred within the API recently

Answer (score 5):

Simple steps to follow and achieve what you want:

for example date is:

```
  String date = "871223";
```

Create [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with source pattern

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd");
```

get the date object by parsing the date

```
    Date d1 = sdf.parse(date);
```

Change the pattern to the target one

```
    sdf.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Format as per the target pattern

```
    System.out.println(sdf.format(d1));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: best answer really!