# String date conversion error in Android

Tags: android, date

I am developing an Android application, which has two EditText boxes and a button.
In the first EditText box, I set the value 13/08/2014. On pressing the button, the value of the first EditText is converted into Date and then inserted into the second EditText.

I use the following code.

```
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String ss=todaysdate.getText().toString();
            Date d1 = df.parse(todaysdate.getText().toString());
```

What happens is, on pressing the button, value of ss and d1 becomes

```
ss = 13/08/2014
d1 = Thu Jan 08 00:00:00 IST 2015
```

See the change, it becomes January 8, 2015

Why is this, and what is the error?

Comment: what is the final format that you want? I assume that *13/08/2014* is the initial format

Comment: The final format is MM/dd/yyyy

Comment: Use yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss

Comment: String date1 = "";
  
Date date3 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
     .parse(date1);
DateFormat df6 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");
System.out.println("output: " + "" + "   " +date1+"::" +df6.format(date3))

Comment: hmmm, so you have date in format `dd/MM/yyyy` and you wana parse it with format `MM/dd/yyyy` ? ... 13th month is january of next year ... so seems to me that the code works like a charm

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607201/convert-date-string-to-perticular-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-in-java

Comment: @Selvin: Then that is supposed to be an error :-(

Comment: it is not an error ... `df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");` you see `MM/dd/yyyy`, again `MM/dd/yyyy` ... `ss = 13/08/2014` you have a `dd/MM/yyyy` format again `dd/MM/yyyy` and again `dd/MM/yyyy` ... `MM/dd/yyyy` != `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: @Yogesh Tatwal : How is it possible to converrt the string date in the EditText.

Comment: Tell me Which is initial format and and Output Is it MM/dd/yyyy to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss ???

Comment: The initial fromat the I read from the EditText is dd/MM/yyyy and I need to get yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss at the end in string format

Comment: It is due to not correct order of Year and month and date.

Comment: One work around you can assign this value to calender and get time from calender in desirable form .

Comment: Can you show me an example @Yogesh

Comment: I had given an answer for it.Please see it below. :-)

Comment: Did you get your answer ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like :-

```
  String date1 = "15/08/2014";
                Date date3 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")
                        .parse(date1);
                Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                newCalendar.setTime(date3);
                            SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

                System.out.println(newCalendar.getTime());

                String formatted = format1.format(newCalendar.getTime());
                System.out.println(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Date date = new Date();
String datestring= f.format(date).toString()
```